# Find the left coset $(13)H$ of $H= \langle (12) \rangle$ in $S_5$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm a bit stuck on this problem. I understand that $S_5$ is the group of symmetries with $n=5$, that's trivial. I'm also aware that there are $120$ subgroups in $S_5$ and $2$ in $H=\langle(12)\rangle$

So thus, the index of $H$ is $60$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

However, I'm just a bit confused on the approach to solving the question stated above.

I've been told that the answer is $123H$, but I prefer to understand the approach than just know the final result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1 \ 2)$ is an involution i.e $(1 \ 2)^2 = e \Rightarrow H = \{e,(1 \ 2)\}$. Then we have;

$$(1\ 3)H = \{(1 \ 3), (1 \ 3) (1 \ 2) = (123) \}$$